# Publishing getting failed in Template rendering but able to preview the Page

Tags: 2013-sp1, templating, template-building-blocks

I am trying to publish an XML Page where I am updating the `Output` of the Page created in **Default Finish Actions** using a C# TBB. I am able to preview the Page in Tridion but while publishing, it is getting failed with the following  error:

I have a page template which generate output in xml format. After default finish action on the PT, I have added a custom c# TBB which reads content from a certain component and adds few nodes to the already generated Output. After that, it simply pushes the Output into package.

> The number of render failures has exceeded its specified failure limit of 0

Error in event viewer in Tridion Template is as below

> Hof.Tridion.BuildingBlocks.PageTemplates.GenerateMegaMenuXml.Transform(Engine engine, Package package) Component: Templating Errorcode: 0 User: NT 
>       AUTHORITY\SYSTEM StackTrace Information Details: at 
>       Hof.Tridion.BuildingBlocks.PageTemplates.GenerateMegaMenuXml.Transform(Engine engine, Package package) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.AssemblyMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.RunTemplate(Engine engine, Package package, String templateUri, String className) at 
>       Tridion.Templating.CSharpTemplate.CSharpSourceTemplate.Transform(Engine __engine, Package __package) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Assembly.CSharpSourceCodeMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package) at 
>       Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformItem(Template template, IdentifiableObject itemToRender) at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.TemplatingRenderer.Render(ResolvedItem resolvedItem, PublishInstruction instruction, PublicationTarget target, RenderedItem renderedItem, RenderContext renderContext)

Can anyone suggest where else to check the exact root cause of issue.

Comment: Are you using publication target in the TBB? what exactly does this TBB? Is it working from Template Builder? If you use Template Builder, probably can have more information about the error.

Comment: No, I am not using publication target in the TBB. The tbb simply gets data from one of the component and add that data to the xml generated in the page "output" field of package. The page is working fine in template builder as well as preview mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things you may want to check:

1. Is the TBB reliant on some/certain content being published to Publishing Target?
2. Is your Publisher scaled out from you CM? If so, then it may be that there's an extension/customisation that has not been installed on the Publisher.
3. Have you made changes to the Compound Template or TBB? If so, then **you'll need to make sure that this template is checked-in**. Template Builder will use the updated version, but publishing uses the last checked-in version.

**Update:** Given how little information you are getting (the old "The number of render failures has exceeded its specified failure limit of 0" message!), I'd suggest that you add more debugging statements to your TBB code and then turn on debug logging on your publisher.

You can find details of logging from the Publisher in the **CMS Publisher Service** section of Elena's blog post here: http://elenaserghie.blogspot.pt/2014/05/tracing-in-sdl-tridion-2013-sp1-walk-in.html

Comment: The Page is an XML page and I am adding a C# TBB after Default Finish Actions which actually picks up the `output` from package and appends a few nodes to the generated XML (get this info form another Component) and pushes back the output to package. There is no use of Publishing Target.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, that was indeed an issue due to checked out page and template. I closed the template builder and checked in the page and it started getting published. Though still, I am not clear on the error message

Answer (score 1):

It would really help if you **edit** your question and provide some more details about what you are exactly doing in your C# TBB.

But gathering from the stack trace your `GenerateMegaMenuXml` TBB is indeed failing in its `Transform` method.

You mention in a comment on @Jonathan's answer that all the TBB does is append a few nodes to the XML in the `Output` item of the package. What would be interesting to know is if the `Output` item contains valid XML and in what way you are trying to serialize it.